# ES6 wrap component within component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

```
const Dropdown = createReactClass({

  render() {
    return 'something'
  }
});

module.exports = enhanceWithClickOutside(Dropdown);
```

How do I use above code in ES6 react?

```
class Dropdown extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return 'something'
    }
}

//where to put the enhanceWithClickOutside?
```

I'm trying to use this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-click-outside

This is my attempt https://codesandbox.io/s/kx48qx7n63

Answer (score 1):

You will need to export the dropdown class. Something like this: `export default enhanceWithClickOutside(Dropdown);`

Edited sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/lp6jo7yjm

Also, see here for another example: https://github.com/davidhu2000/react-spinners/blob/master/examples/components/color_picker.jsx

Comment: what is line 10 for?. Can you refer to the doc https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-click-outside, I don't see the need for that. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You're right, it wasn't needed. I updated the codesandbox

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';

const Dropdown = () => ('something');

export default Dropdown;
```

OR, if you want to do some computation before return

```
import React from 'react';

const Dropdown = props => {
    // do your computations
    return 'something';
};

export default Dropdown;
```